# How does LCD display work with VGA connector?

Tags: lcd, vga, connector

it's said that:

*"As an inherently digital device, the LCD can natively display digital data from a DVI or HDMI connection without requiring conversion to analog."*

From here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal_display

But what if i use LCD display with VGA connector?

VGA connector is analog. Does this mean LCD display will use Analogue-to-Digital Converter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, an LCD with a VGA connector has an analog-to-digital converter between the VGA input and the rest of the display circuitry.